# php if statement that checks if the month and day match mysql db date field

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an if statement in php where if the month and day match what i have in my database, then the user receives a happy anniversary message. Else if they do not match the user receives a welcome message.

```
if(month($row['date'])==month(now()) && day($row['date'])==day(now())){
        echo "Happy Anniversary";
    }else{
        echo "Welcome";
    }
```

As of now I receive the following error message: **Fatal error: Call to undefined function MONTH().**

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing mysql syntax and php syntax together.

> [month()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php) and [now()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-now/) are mysql functions

Thats why php is giving error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined function MONTH().

You can php [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function 
So do like this

```
$time=strtotime($row['date']);
if(date("m",$time)==date("m") && date("d",$time)==date("d")){
    echo "Happy Anniversary";
}else{
    echo "Welcome";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that for me. I was able to apply the changes and it works now! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what is the format of the date that you're capturing, I'm assuming one for you to use. [$row[date] = "2010-08-12"]

```
$d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $row[date]);
if($d["month"]==date("M") && $d("day")==date("d"){
    echo "Happy Anniversary";
}else{
    echo "Welcome";
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `month` and `day` functions in `php` they are `mysql` functions.Try this use `DateTime`;

```
<?php
$row['date']='2017-01-08';
        $now = new DateTime('now');
   $month = $now->format('m');
   $date = $now->format('d');
   $r=new DateTime($row['date']);
$rmonth=$r->format('m');
$rdate=$r->format('d');

if($rmonth==$month && $rdate==$date){
        echo "Happy Anniversary";
    }else{
        echo "Welcome";
    }
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8bc158938ac3eadf1ccc7121a103f4961d1f9408)